# How can i capture the event of a tapped item (located in a template) from the base class?

Tags: xaml, events, xamarin, binding, event-handling

I have a base grid

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="GridName">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                <art:GridOptionsView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >
                    <art:GridOptionsView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <uikit:DashboardItemTemplate />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </art:GridOptionsView.ItemTemplate>
                </art:GridOptionsView>
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
```

which uses the following DashboardItemTemplate

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
        BackgroundColor="White">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <Grid Padding="0">
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="10">
                <Grid>
                    <Label Text="" Style="{StaticResource FontIcon}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Opacity="1" FontSize="130" TextColor="{Binding BackgroundColor}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" IsVisible="{Binding Source={x:Reference Root}, Path=ShowiconColoredCircleBackground}" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding Icon}" Style="{StaticResource FontIcon}" Opacity="1" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                </Grid>
                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="{Binding Source={x:Reference Root}, Path=TextColor}" FontSize="14" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center">
                </Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
    </ContentView.Content>
    <ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnWidgetTapped" />
    </ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
</ContentView>
```

How can i capture the "OnWidgetTapped" event on my base xaml class?

Comment: Are you using Grial component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do this usually with a custom bindable property `ParentBindingContext` in my template:

```
public class MyTemplate : ContentPage
{
    public static BindableProperty ParentBindingContextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ParentBindingContext), 
        typeof(object), typeof(BasePageTemplate));


    public object ParentBindingContext
    {
        get { return GetValue(ParentBindingContextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ParentBindingContextProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

And then in your page (which contains the template) just set the `ParentBindingContext`:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <template:MyTemplate ParentBindingContext="{Binding BindingContext, Source={x:Reference Name=MyPageName}}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

With that you can access the full `BindingContext` of your page in your template. The following example of a command shows how the template can bind to a command `MyCommand`, which is in the `BindingContext` of the page:

```
Command="{Binding ParentBindingContext.MyCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=MyTemplatePageName}}"
```

But this presupposes that your page has a `BindingContext` behind (like a ViewModel). This ViewModel then contains the "global" commands for the whole page. These commands (or just methods) can then be accessed by the template, because they know about the `BindingContext` of the page.

Comment: Can you please tell what is BasePageTemplate? and i am assigning the template based on some condition via DataTemplateSelector. I have a different templates to show depending on the current Model.
where can i set the ParentBindingContext?

Comment: The `BasePageTemplate` is the name of the template's class. For the example above it would be `DashboardItemTemplate`

Answer (score 1):

I changed an answer from flow description to the code. The idea is to create ItemTemplate programatically and pass to its constructor the page with list (or grid). Define a function ItemTemplateTapped and call it from template.

EventOnGridPage

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ButtonRendererDemo.EventOnGridPage">

 <ListView x:Name="listView" >
</ListView>           
</ContentPage>
```

EventOnGridPage code behind

```
public partial class EventOnGridPage : ContentPage
{

    public EventOnGridPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

       listView.ItemsSource = new List<Contact>
       {
           new Contact { Name = "Kirti",Status = "True"},
           new Contact { Name = "Nilesh",Status = "False"}
       };

        listView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(loadTemplate);
    }

    private object loadTemplate()
    {
        return new ViewCell() { View = new EventOnGridTemplate(this) };
    }

    public void ItemTemplateTapped(string name)
    {
        DisplayAlert("ItemTemplateTapped", name, "OK");
    }
}
```

EventOnGridTemplate xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ButtonRendererDemo.EventOnGridTemplate"
             BackgroundColor="Green">

  <Label Text="{Binding Name}" x:Name="myLabel"></Label>

</ContentView>
```

EventOnGridTemplate code behind

```
public partial class EventOnGridTemplate
{
    EventOnGridPage parent;

    public EventOnGridTemplate(EventOnGridPage parent)
    {
        this.parent = parent;

        InitializeComponent();

        var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped;
        myLabel.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);

    }

    private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         parent.ItemTemplateTapped(myLabel.Text);

    }
}
```

Comment: I must confess I am totally impressed and I wish I could follow the whole flow behind this

Comment: I will do some code with grid but cannot exactly reproduce Grial. Is that acceptable for you?

Comment: sure that won't be a problem

Comment: Sorry :-) regular grid doesn't have item source and it is not templatable, so my code will be based on ListView but idea is the same

Comment: And if all that is too complicated just use Messenger :-) Subscribe in Page and Fire from template. Though some people don't like to use messenger and try to avoid it at all costs

Comment: @YuriS Why do people try to avoid messenger?

Comment: @Zure From my perspective it is useful in some situations. Here is some discussions. https://xamarinhelp.com/common-misuse-messagingcenter/ There are more in linked in "Xamarin Forms" group

Comment: @OrElse Any of answers worked for you? There is another option to create an event in template and when you create template the page can subscribe to that event. This is about the same as the solution I described above.

Comment: @Zure Hello all. After countless efforts I solved it by using the messenger style. Actually I didn't know the existence of it prior to this post. The only thing that is frightening me, is any  memory - performance issues, since I am passing a structure of items within it..

Answer (score 0):

You just need to implement your `OnWidgetTapped` method:

```
void OnWidgetTapped(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // Do stuff here
}
```

Comment: I actually want to raise the OnWidgetTapped event in the base grid not within the template itself. How can i accomplish this ? Something like event += new event, into the gridview

Answer (score 0):

If you already defined the tap gesture binding in the XAML code, you don't need to add the TapGestureRecognizer, simply sign your method to an event listener method:

Your XAML:

```
<ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnWidgetTapped" />
</ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
```

On C# code behind:

```
public void OnWidgetTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
// do stuff here
}
```

Comment: I actually want to raise the OnWidgetTapped event in the base grid not within the template itself. How can i accomplish this ? Something like event += new event, into the gridview

Answer (score 0):

Another solution. If you implemented OnWidgetTapped as was suggested you can use sender.Parent.Parent... till you get to the object you want - grid or page. Cast it to for example EventOnGridPage and then call the function of that object.