# BindingContext with command and parameter binding

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a ViewModel, from which i construct a collection of objects. I want to be able to bind my objects on my view, while at the same time being able to use my `button`.

Currently, my properties are correctly bound to my labels (partnerLogo, partnerText, partnerLink). Unfortunately I'm not able to use my button command to send the command parameter that I bind.

ViewModel

```
Public class CarouselViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public CarouselViewModel()
    {
        partners = new ObservableCollection<Carousel>()
        {
            new Carousel(){partnerText = "Test123", partnerLogo = "Test123", partnerLink = "Test123" },
        };

        openWebsite = new Command<string>((key) =>
        {
            Device.OpenUri(new Uri(key));
        });
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Carousel> partners
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public ICommand openWebsite
    {
        private set;
        get;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding partners}">
    <CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
        <GridItemsLayout/>
             </CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
                 <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                     <DataTemplate>
                          <Frame>
                              <StackLayout>
                                  <Image Source="{Binding partnerLogo}"/>
                                  <Label Text="{Binding partnerText}"/>
                                  <Button Text="Read" Command="{Binding openWebsite}" CommandParameter="{Binding partnerLink}"/>
                             </StackLayout>
                         </Frame>
                     </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselView>
```

How do I access my button command, while at the same time being able to send the commandparameter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin Forms Button Command binding inside a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40913439/xamarin-forms-button-command-binding-inside-a-listview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each item in the `CarouselView`, the binding context will be underlying data item which is bound to `ItemsSource` i.e., `Carousel`. And for `CarouselView`, the binding context will be your `ViewModel` class **if you have defined it**.

To resolve the issue, set the x:Name="mycaroselview" to `CarouselView` in the XAML and refer it's path reference to the Button command as like below code example.

```
<CarouselView x:Name="MyCarousel" ItemsSource="{Binding partners}">
<CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
    <GridItemsLayout/>
         </CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
             <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                      <Frame>
                          <StackLayout>
                              <Image Source="{Binding partnerLogo}"/>
                              <Label Text="{Binding partnerText}"/>
                              <Button Text="Read" Command="{Binding BindingContext.openWebsite, Source={x:Reference Name=MyCarousel}}" CommandParameter="{Binding partnerLink}"/>
                         </StackLayout>
                     </Frame>
                 </DataTemplate>
        </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
```

Make sure that you must set the binding context either to `ContentPage` or `CarouselView`.

Regards, 
Dinesh

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, give a `x:name` to the content Page that you are using:-

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject;assembly= MyProject"
             x:Class="MyProject.Views.MyPage"
             x:Name="ThisPage">
```

And then give Source to the Command. Like this. This method will call the Command that is there in the ViewModel of the Current Page. Also, you can use a Command Parameter to know which Item has Triggered the Command.

```
<CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding partners}">
    <CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
        <GridItemsLayout/>
             </CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
                 <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                     <DataTemplate>
                          <Frame>
                              <StackLayout>
                                  <Image Source="{Binding partnerLogo}"/>
                                  <Label Text="{Binding partnerText}"/>
                                  <Button Text="Read" Command="{Binding openWebsite, Source={x:Reference Name=ThisPage}}" CommandParameter="{Binding partnerLink}"/>
                             </StackLayout>
                         </Frame>
                     </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselView>
```